# About using the EmguCV on Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, emgucv

I would like to use the EmguCV library on the Azure function. However, it always pop up an error "Unable to load DLL 'cvextern' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)" while test running.
The package references in function.proj as follow:

```
<PackageReference Include="Emgu.CV" Version="4.5.3.4721" />
<PackageReference Include="Emgu.CV.Bitmap" Version="4.5.3.4721" />
<PackageReference Include="Emgu.CV.runtime.windows" Version="4.5.3.4721" />
```

I know that there is another topic mentioned before ([Emgucv ver 4.2 on Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116188/emgucv-ver-4-2-on-azure-function)), but it seems doesn't work in my case. I also tried to use the version 4.2.0.3662, it also doesn't work due to the "Emgu.CV.Bitmap" doesn't have the version 4.2.0.3662 in Nuget.

My question is that how can I run the EmguCV on my Azure function? The runtime version of Azure function is 3.1.3.0.

Super thanks for your help and patient.

Answer (score 1):

Create Azure Function - Version v3 with .Net 5 .
Include EmguCV library from Nuget Packages.
Make sure all the latest packages related to EmguCV are included in Dependencies folder without missing.

**Steps to Install** :

Right Click on ProjectName -> Manage Nuget Packages- Browse -> Enter the package name to be included and Install.
Check package references in .csproj file. Build the project, run it.

[image]